# asp.net webforms reusable page design

Tags: asp.net, webforms, user-controls

I need design ideas for a webform project I am working on. The public side of the project is complete with a bunch of ASPX pages in a as usual master page. Now I need to create the admin side of the project where the admin staff can load the pages such that they are looking the client page all "framed" in a master page that has number of filter/search controls to get to the right client page. I want to reuse the markup and code-behind I've already created for the client side.

In the old days I would have created a frameset with the admin side controls in the top-frame and the client pages in the bottom frame. It all worked out fine then, but as we know, frameset are not supported in html5. What is the alternative you suggest should be the best way to achieve this goal in the Webforms way of doing things.

I know that there may be some use of Usercontrols somewhere in the solution, but I don't know how exactly this will all come together. If there are any best practice solution out there then please inform me of them.

Thanks.

Comment: Just wrap your pages in different master pages (with admin controls.

Comment: Do you mean two copies of each page with different master page tag at the top?

Comment: The same page using different master pages. Master page should be set in Page_PreInit handler

Comment: Good pointers, but how am I going to maintain the viewstate (textbox's text property, or selectedvalue of dropdownlist etc) of the admin controls from one public page to another, because the master page will be reloading from ground up every time. if possible, I would prefer the child/public pages to be totally agnostic of the master page context they are running under. For that reason I was thinking in the line of Usercontrols. I appreciate your responses. Please don't feel like I am shooting down your ideas. Just trying to work out things ahead of time.

Comment: How about instead of frameset, you make a div container with just iFrames? I have used in some cases iFrame on HTML5 sites those work fine.